# Migrating JMS Queue from Hypersonic to MSSQL

Tags: jboss, jms

I am currently trying to replace Hypersonic with MS-SQL 2008 R2 in JBoss AS 5.1.0GA.

I have followed the instructions in the JBoss Server Configuration Guide, however the server fails to load with this error:

> 2013-09-26 17:06:04,479 WARN  [org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivation] (WorkManager(2)-3) Failure in jms activation org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsActivationSpec@8bb1eb(ra=org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.JmsResourceAdapter@c54851 destination=queue/iam/im/jms/queue/wpUtilQueue destinationType=javax.jms.Queue tx=true durable=false reconnect=10 provider=DefaultJMSProvider user=null maxMessages=1 minSession=1 maxSession=15 keepAlive=30000 useDLQ=true DLQHandler=org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.dlq.GenericDLQHandler DLQJndiName=queue/DLQ DLQUser=null DLQMaxResent=10)
>       javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DLQ not bound

(I left out the stack trace for brevity; it isn't important.)
I have checked, and DLQ is defined in destinations-service.xml

I'm not sure where to proceed from here; every response I can find on Google seems to suggest that defining the queue in destinations-service.xml has solved the issue for almost everyone.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The "dead letter queue" is possibly persistent, and the storage is possibly in Hypersonic. Do you use JMS? Do you want to use MS SQL to be used by JMS? Otherwise I suggest keeping Hypersonic in JBoss.

Comment: Yes, I am using JMS, and yes I want JMS to use MS SQL. Hypersonic is not recommended for use in a production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the instructions in the Configuration Guide aren't 100% complete. The issue was that a ChannelFactory was referenced in the mssql-persistence-service.xml; however, this environment is not clustered, and so there were no ChannelFactory objects defined.

Removing the reference to the ChannelFactory was sufficient to resolve the issue.